# What should I use for technically always read-only objects?

Tags: design, design-patterns, c++, c++11

I have a function `get()` which gets a `human` object from somewhere. That is literally the only use of `human`, to provide a collection of properties of a `human`.

```
struct human {
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    unsigned int age;
    std::string location;
};
```

Doing things like

```
human user;
user.first_name = "Foo";
```

doesn't really make sense, because `human` is only supposed to be used to read the properties of the object that `get()` returns, if that makes sense.

```
human user = get();
std::cout << user.age << '\n';
```

It should effectively be a read-only struct. I think it makes sense to enforce this, as if you accidently modify the data, you'll maybe be surprised to see that it changed or has a weird value.

I thought of declaring the properties `private` and providing getter functions like `first_name()` and `age()`. Making every member variable `const` is also not ideal, because that would remove the implicit copy constructor.

But I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve this, because those two methods require a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: typedef human const struct _human{...} ?

Comment: Does `get` create a `human` out of thin air, or just provide read-access to an existing one? In the latter case, return by constant reference.

Comment: @Deduplicator It creates one out of thin air :)

Comment: @Walfrat That wouldn't work nicely, as `typedef` (or `using`) doesn't create a new type. Basically `std::decay_t<human>` would result in a `_human`.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do ? Forbid another developer to modify the data in memory ? In a persistant storage ? Others ? Why would a (competent enough) developer that need only to read the data to do its job will modify it ? Otherwise check Deduplicator suggestion.

Comment: @Walfrat I don't know, but a developer might modify it accidently. It's pretty defensive though, yes. It's just acting like a safeguard to prevent accidental modifications.

Comment: Use a class, private member, getter member function and a constructor that initialize all fields.

Comment: @Phil1970 I know about that already, but I wanted to avoid it because it requires me to write a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: What makes you think declaring any members const removes the copy constructor?

Comment: @Caleth The following for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/26131921/3980929

Comment: @Rakete1111 that's copy assignment. `human instance = get();` is fine

Comment: @Caleth Oh sorry, I thought you meant copy in general. `instance = instance2` is not ok, which is not ok for my purposes.

Comment: You could always make the member variables const, but i dont think it should be necesarry

Answer (score 5):

Make the members private but do not make them const. Provide getters but no setters and mark your getters const.  now your object is copiable but the client cannot modify the values.  You will have to provide all values in the constructor.  Boilerplate code is unavoidable here.

You could have your function return a const Human, but that does little more than hint to the developer that it is not to be modified.